# NSNotification sent data is blank after page is loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, notifications

I am sending data from ViewController 1 to ViewController 3 and from ViewController 2 to ViewController 3 via NSNotification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("retirementChange", object: retirementText?.text)
```

I print the data from ViewController 3 when I set the data from NSNotification to a variable in ViewController 3. I set the variable age to the notification object.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setRetirementAge:", name: "retirementChange", object: nil)

func setRetirementAge(notification: NSNotification){
    age = notification.object!
    print(age)
}
```

It prints fine in the console at that time, But then when I try to use the value age once the page is loaded it is BLANK.

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why are you using NSNotification and not just passing the data via variables in you ViewControllers ?

Comment: I have static table cells

Comment: Why are you storing data in a view controller and not a data model. Anyway, how is `age` declared, when and where.

Comment: good comment Zaph. And I don't understand why you can't pass data around with variables even if you have static cells, there is no relation between them...

Comment: It is declared in ViewController 3 `var age: AnyObject = ""`

Comment: How are you view controllers managed?  Are you sure that the instance of viewcontroller3 that is being presented is the instance that is receiving the notification?

Answer (score 1):

You should take into account what was mentioned in the comments of your question and perhaps not use `NSNotification` but pass data to the controllers in an orderly fashion. Notifications are actually meant to notify controllers that are on screen when something is changing somewhere else, typically on a background thread. The proper way is to set the correct data to be displayed just before a view controller appears. It should be set either by some available data model, or via variables that are set by the presenting view controller in the usual methods such as `prepareForSegue`.

That being said, it seems from your code that you misunderstand the `object` parameter when sending the notification. The `object` just restricts the scope of the notification. If you want to pass data you have to create a new `NSNotification` and include a `userInfo` dictionary with any data you want the receiver to get.

```
let notif = NSNotification(name: "retirementChange", object: nil, userInfo: ["age": 42])
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notif)
```